# Create same app for multiple user

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, xcode5

I have developed an app for one user(/role type) and now wish to add more roles for the same app. So now, different roles will show/hide some functionality **depending on the roles** assigned. Obviously I will have the same login page to enter inside the single app which is the start point for checking the roles. Doing so will save my screen count for the app. How to achieve this effectively?

Any design ideas to show multiple roles logged in will also be accepted.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is the problem you're having with this?

Comment: I have no issues, I need just a proper way to achieve the above requirement. Mainly showing/hiding features depending on roles. i thought of it by using flags, but it won't be a effective solution I guess....

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can create an bitmask enum representing your differents roles

```
typedef enum : NSUInteger {
  RoleType1 = (1 << 0), // = 001
  RoleType2 = (1 << 1), // = 010
  RoleType3 = (1 << 2)  // = 100
} RoleType;
```

Using a bitmask allow you to assign many roles to your user

For exemple you can do :

```
RoleType myRoles = RoleType1|RoleType2 // here myRoles = 011
```

To assign both RoleType1 and RoleType2 to your user

Then Stock this somewhere (AppDelegate `@property` maybe ?)

```
@property (nonatomic) RoleType myRoles;

((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).myRoles = RoleType1|RoleType2
```

Then you just have to test what roles does your user have to show some content in screen or entry in menu, etc...

```
// We get the current roles
RoleType myRoles = ((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).myRoles
if (myRoles & RoleType1) { // This is the way to test if myRoles and RoleType1 have a common bit
  // Then user has role1, then we want to show a button for example
  button.hidden = NO;
} else {
  // User does not have role1
  button.hidden = YES
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the valuable reply. I wish if you could go a bit in implementation detail about it.

Comment: @user2741735 I added more details